# How to blink a label using Task

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want an extension method to blink labels on Windows Form ...

So i wrote the following code ...

```
private static ConcurrentBag<Task> Tasks = new ConcurrentBag<Task>();
private static CancellationTokenSource cts = null;

public static void Blink(this Label label, string text)
{
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    Task task = new Task(async () =>
    {
        label.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            label.Text = text;
            label.Visible = true;
        }));
        while (true)
        {
            label.Invoke((Action)(() => { label.Visible = !label.Visible; }));
            if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
            { 
                break; 
            }
            await Task.Delay(600);
        }
        label.Invoke((Action)(() => { label.Visible = false; }));
    },cts.Token);

    Tasks.Add(task);
    task.Start();
}
```

And some code to stop ...

```
public static void Stop(this Label label)
{
   if (cts != null)
   {
       cts.Cancel();                
   }
}
```

If i have two buttons one with Blink and one with Stop , everything is fine ...
My problem is if i have a button with the following code ...

```
label1.Blink("Hello World!");
label1.Blink("Hi");
```

I need a way to cancel the first Task before starting the second one on the Blink method ...

Comment: I don't know why but it does not work.

Comment: I have a scenario on my application where the same label should change its Text and Blink.That's the point.The Stop with a Blink in sequence does not give time for canceling the Task.I tried Task.WhenAll(Tasks.ToArray()) without sucess ...

Comment: Why do you mix blinking with setting the text of the label?  Blinking should not set the text.  Case closed.

Comment: Why not ? This is not the point ... The point is to cancel the first Task in an appropriate manner ...

Comment: Return the cancellation token from the `Blink()` method and you should be able to cancel the task. Oh, also, generate the cancellation token from within the method. Get rid of the static instance.

Comment: Spawning threads to perform blinking, a total overkill. Use an observer pattern rather.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few problems with the solution as-is. For one, the cancellation tokens are `static`, so they'll be shared between *all* blinking labels. For another, the code is overly complicated by using the task constructor, `Start`, and `Control.Invoke`.

A much simpler approach would look like:

```
public static Tuple<Task, CancellationTokenSource> Blink(this Label label)
{
  var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
  var task = BlinkAsync(label, cts.Token);
  return Tuple.Create(task, cts);
}

private static Task BlinkAsync(Label label, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  label.Visible = true;
  while (true)
  {
    label.Visible = !label.Visible;
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    await Task.Delay(600);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
var runningBlink = label.Blink();
...
runningBlink.Item2.Cancel(); // to stop
```

Comment: What do you think if i extend Label control to have a CancellationTokenSource as a property to cancel it in the Blink method ?

Comment: @user3641815: If you're going to extend `Label`, why use a CTS or blink method at all? Why not just have an `IsBlinking` property?

Comment: I was obsessed with the solution i had in mind and saw no other alternative Anyway thanks!